# How can I insert a row in Excel, at the selected location using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button14_Click()
    Rows("14:14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the above code to copy a row. Now, it inserts directly below the copied row but my objective is to insert this row at any selected row. The code will be assigned to a button which would return the copied cells at the selected location on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does a selection, actively negating any selection you might have.
If you copy without selecting first, you can have it paste at the row selected when running the macro.

```
Sub Button14_Click()
   Rows("14:14").Copy
   Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

If you don't want to insert a new row – which would probably break the code if inserted above row 14, actively moving the row you want to copy to 15 – you could do this:

```
Sub Button14_Click()
    Rows(14).Copy Rows(Selection.Row)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work now. But the problem is that i have few formulas in the row and i need that as well.

Comment: .copy should bring all the formulas as well. If that comment was for my `.values` edit, then I'm sorry, I removed that again.

Comment: .value worked for my case. The only addition that i would need is that instead of values, I need to result to include the formulas as well

Comment: What if you use this one row copy, that doesn't insert?